# How to add objects to this array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a get route for a page which displays user info. In this I have created a list array which I have passed to render object and this list contains 2 things one is user image which is displaying correctly and the other is his attendance in form of an array which includes different objects.

The problem is when I am pushing this objects they are not getting added to the dates array and are not getting displayed in the list array.
Also when I am console logging the objects they are getting displayed individually.

```
router.get("/me", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    var empCode = req.user.empCode;
    var list = []
    list.photo = await Document.findOne({
        empCode: empCode
    }).then(employee => {
        return employee.photo;
    });


    list.attendance = await Attendance.findOne({
        empCode: empCode
    }).then(employee => {    
        var dates = [];    
        var emp = {};
        employee.years.forEach(year => {
            yearName = year.name;
            emp["year"] = yearName;
            year.months.forEach(month => {
                monthName = month.name;
                emp["month"] = monthName;
                month.days.forEach(day => {
                    date = day.date;
                    inTime = day.inTime;
                    outTime = day.outTime;
                    status = day.status;
                    emp["date"] = date;
                    emp["inTime"] = inTime;
                    emp["outTime"] = outTime;
                    emp["status"] = status;
                    dates.push(emp); // Here is i console log the objects are getting displayed.
                });                
            });            
        });
        return dates;
    });

    console.log(list);
    res.render("me", {
        user: req.user,
        list
    });
});
```

If I `console.log(emp);` in forEach loop this is the result.

```
{
  year: '2020',
  month: 'Jan',
  date: '1',
  inTime: '09:40',
  outTime: '18:10',
  status: 'On Time'
}
{
  year: '2020',
  month: 'Feb',
  date: '3',
  inTime: '10:15',
  outTime: '18:15',
  status: 'Late'
}
{
  year: '2020',
  month: 'Feb',
  date: '4',
  inTime: '10:20',
  outTime: '18:20',
  status: 'Late'
}
[ photo: '', attendance: [] ]
```

But if I do `dates.push(emp);` then I get.

```
[
  photo: '',
  attendance: [
    {
      year: '2020',
      month: 'Feb',
      date: '4',
      inTime: '10:20',
      outTime: '18:20',
      status: 'Late'
    },
    {
      year: '2020',
      month: 'Feb',
      date: '4',
      inTime: '10:20',
      outTime: '18:20',
      status: 'Late'
    },
    {
      year: '2020',
      month: 'Feb',
      date: '4',
      inTime: '10:20',
      outTime: '18:20',
      status: 'Late'
    }
  ]
]
```

And what I want is this.

```
[
  photo: '',
  attendance: [
    {
  year: '2020',
  month: 'Jan',
  date: '1',
  inTime: '09:40',
  outTime: '18:10',
  status: 'On Time'
}
{
  year: '2020',
  month: 'Feb',
  date: '3',
  inTime: '10:15',
  outTime: '18:15',
  status: 'Late'
}
{
  year: '2020',
  month: 'Feb',
  date: '4',
  inTime: '10:20',
  outTime: '18:20',
  status: 'Late'
}
  ]
]
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: this code should display 3 objects in attendance array but instead it displays last object 3 times.

Comment: Could you copy and paste your expected output and your current output into your original post? Also to clarify, you're saying you're getting the correct output when you log `emp` while in the `forEach` loop?

Comment: please check i have updated the question with the results i am getting and what is want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your variable `emp` to a new instance of object. you should push to array like this.

```
dates.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emp));
```

This will convert your variable emp into a new instance of object without any connection to the object you were accessing during your iteration.

> Variables that are assigned a non-primitive value are given a
>   reference to that value. That reference points to the object’s
>   location in memory. The variables don’t actually contain the value.

**Primitives vs. References**
Please read this docs to understand further [value vs reference](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

Comment: hi i am stuck after this step too can you please help this is the post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073924/how-to-pass-array-received-from-node-js-to-script